# How to render an array of objects (label,value pair) effectively on a lightning checkbox group functioning as a dropdown?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom, lightning-combobox, lightning-checkbox-group

I need a checkbox group as a dropdown and have the following array formed in LWC JS

```
handleShowingStateFilters(resultSet){

        this.stateFilterOptions = [];
        this.tempArray = Object.keys(resultSet).map((key) => (
            {
                label: key, 
                value: resultSet[key]
            }
        ));
        let randomArray =[];

        (this.tempArray).forEach(item =>{
            if(!randomArray.includes (item)){

                randomArray.push(item);
            }

        })

        this.stateFilterOptions =[...randomArray];
        console.log('state filters for district', this.stateFilterOptions);
    }
```

This gives output successfully as I see in console
[image]

Issue is I am trying to render these values as a checkbox group appearing as a dropdown, since I cannot directly use a lightning-combobox, I am using SLDS picklist. Here is the code I am using on the template side

```
    <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-size_small">
                <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click">
                <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                <div role="combobox" tabindex="0" class="slds-input_faux slds-combobox__input" aria-labelledby="combobox-label-id-38 combobox-id-1-selected-value" id="combobox-id-1-selected-value" aria-controls="listbox-id-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox">
                <span class="slds-truncate" id="combobox-value-id-46" lwc:if={isMyDistrictActive}>States</span>
                <span class="slds-truncate" id="combobox-value-id-47" lwc:else>Divisions</span>

                </div>
                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-down slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">
                    <lightning-icon icon-name='utility:down' alternative-text='down' size='x-small' title='down'></lightning-icon>

                </span>
                </div>
                <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox" aria-label="drop down items" tabindex="0" aria-busy="false">

                    <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-p-vertical_medium filter-list-state scrollbar scrollbar-track">
                        <lightning-checkbox-group lwc:if={isMyDistrictActive} class="force-overflow" name="Checkbox Group"
                            variant="label-hidden"
                            options={stateFilterOptions}
                            value={value}
                            onchange={handleStateFilter}></lightning-checkbox-group>

                            <lightning-checkbox-group lwc:else class="force-overflow" name="Checkbox Group"
                            variant="label-hidden"
                            options={divisionFilterOptions}
                            value={value}
                            onchange={handleDivisionFilter}></lightning-checkbox-group>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

I have used the default picklist slds code from documentation and just replaced the ul and li items with a checkboxgroup to show it as a dropdown. Here is the link:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/picklist/#Default

The problem is the values are not showing when I click the bar and the console shows error:
[image]

[image]

the console shows issue here at the last line and I have not written this method, I assume LWR site generates this in the browser:
[image]

Comment: @sfdcfox your inputs would be highly valuable here